# How to remove Calendar on Woocommerce Category Pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Woocommerce. On my Category pages, there is a calendar. How do I remove it?

Of note is that as a Category, it is *not* a page I can edit directly using Elementor. when I go to the admin dashboard and click pages, the category pages are not listed.

URLs of Category "Pages":

[www.example.com/product-category/**year-round-blends**/](http://www.example.com/product-category/**year-round-blends**/)

[www.example.com/product-category/**fall](http://www.example.com/product-category/**fall) blends**/

etc

Notable plugins I'm using:
Woocommerce, Yith, and Elementor.

[image]

Comment: It's looks more like a widget in your sidebar the below your Search bar, have a glance in your Appearence->widgets

Comment: @RachChen You are a lifesaver. That worked. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RachChen I glanced at your profile and saw you live in Taipei. I live in Kaohsiung!

Comment: no worries, so glad to hear that worked. Actually, I have not live there many years ago Lol